# Azure Devops Work Item Tracking API does not return dates according to server timezone (on-premise server)

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2020

In the following page MS states that Azure Devops server stores all dates as UTC:
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/timezone-settings-usage?view=azure-devops)

There is no way to change this on-premise server.

There is no option to get the data in the servers local time zone using the API also:
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

I am trying to get data from API and send query results as email,since there is no browser in between all the dates are wrong because of this reason.

How can I get query results from this API and make sure dates are in servers timezone?
Please note that date columns in queries can change.

Comment: As the consumer of the data, it's up to you to convert from UTC to the appropriate timezone. Are you having difficulty implementing timezone conversion?